# What do when after a question the right answer is no one of the answer but a sum of all of this ?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, information-display

I have [asked a question about what to do when coding feel boring and the same all over again](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38225/what-to-do-when-coding-begins-to-feel-boring-like-it-is-all-just-more-of-the-sam). All the answer can be for a community point of view right, so there is no one answer right, but the right question is a little sum of all the answer, what can i do in this case ?

[the related question is this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38225/what-to-do-when-coding-begins-to-feel-boring-like-it-is-all-just-more-of-the-sam)

Answer (score 5):

Some questions on Programmers.SE do not have just one correct answer and that is okay. I would just leave it as is.

Alternatively, if one answer stands out above all others (with more information, detail, better reasoning, etc), I would accept that one. You can also use upvotes as a guide and accept the answer with the highest number of votes, although the most popular answer may not be the most useful, so use your best judgement there.

Comment: Sound advice as always.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've never seen a need to close a question, maybe you can edit your question by adding a note where you describe the situation. But as far as I know, there could be always question with no right answer.

Answer (score -4):

I believe a good solution is to create a community wiki answer that sums up all the answers and accept that one.

Comment: That'd just duplicate information on the page with little benefit to it. You'd also then have to maintain that answer in case anybody else added an answer or edited what they said earlier to avoid having the accepted CW answer go out of date.

Comment: @Anna: I believe it depends on the context, on stack overflow there might not be one single answer that 100% answers the question so the asker might sum up the solution afterwards instead of leaving the solution to the reader. Maybe in programmers.SE where questions are more subjective, multiple answers are good but none will ever be the true right answer.